# Python ImportError: DLL load failed: The specified module could not be found on fman build system (fbs)

Tags: python, python-3.6, pyinstaller, fbs

I encountered error when i am trying to convert my python scripts to EXE using fman build system (fbs). This error happened when i tried to run the program on Python 3.6 in cmd in virtual environment.

I am using Python 3.6 and pyinstaller 3.4. Below are the list of library im using.

```
altgraph (0.17)
cycler (0.10.0)
fbs (0.8.4)
future (0.18.2)
joblib (0.14.1)
kiwisolver (1.1.0)
macholib (1.14)
matplotlib (3.1.2)
numpy (1.18.1)
opencv-contrib-python (4.1.2.30)
opencv-python (4.1.2.30)
pefile (2019.4.18)
pip (9.0.1)
PyInstaller (3.4)
pyparsing (2.4.6)
PyQt5 (5.9.2)
python-dateutil (2.8.1)
pywin32-ctypes (0.2.0)
scikit-learn (0.22.1)
scipy (1.4.1)
setuptools (39.1.0)
sip (4.19.8)
six (1.14.0)
webcolors (1.10)
```

Below are the error i received:

```
(venv) D:\Skripsi\ColorHarmonization-master\target\ColorHarmonization>ColorHarmonization.exe
d:\skripsi\colorharmonization-master\venv\lib\site-packages\PyInstaller\loader\pyimod03_importers.py:627: MatplotlibDeprecationWarning:
The MATPLOTLIBDATA environment variable was deprecated in Matplotlib 3.1 and will be removed in 3.3.
  exec(bytecode, module.__dict__)
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "main.py", line 7, in <module>
  File "d:\skripsi\colorharmonization-master\venv\lib\site-packages\PyInstaller\loader\pyimod03_importers.py", line 627, in exec_module
    exec(bytecode, module.__dict__)
  File "util.py", line 8, in <module>
  File "d:\skripsi\colorharmonization-master\venv\lib\site-packages\PyInstaller\loader\pyimod03_importers.py", line 627, in exec_module
    exec(bytecode, module.__dict__)
  File "lib\site-packages\sklearn\__init__.py", line 82, in <module>
  File "d:\skripsi\colorharmonization-master\venv\lib\site-packages\PyInstaller\loader\pyimod03_importers.py", line 627, in exec_module
    exec(bytecode, module.__dict__)
  File "lib\site-packages\sklearn\base.py", line 20, in <module>
  File "d:\skripsi\colorharmonization-master\venv\lib\site-packages\PyInstaller\loader\pyimod03_importers.py", line 627, in exec_module
    exec(bytecode, module.__dict__)
  File "lib\site-packages\sklearn\utils\__init__.py", line 27, in <module>
  File "d:\skripsi\colorharmonization-master\venv\lib\site-packages\PyInstaller\loader\pyimod03_importers.py", line 627, in exec_module
    exec(bytecode, module.__dict__)
  File "lib\site-packages\sklearn\utils\fixes.py", line 18, in <module>
  File "d:\skripsi\colorharmonization-master\venv\lib\site-packages\PyInstaller\loader\pyimod03_importers.py", line 627, in exec_module
    exec(bytecode, module.__dict__)
  File "lib\site-packages\scipy\stats\__init__.py", line 384, in <module>
  File "d:\skripsi\colorharmonization-master\venv\lib\site-packages\PyInstaller\loader\pyimod03_importers.py", line 627, in exec_module
    exec(bytecode, module.__dict__)
  File "lib\site-packages\scipy\stats\stats.py", line 179, in <module>
  File "d:\skripsi\colorharmonization-master\venv\lib\site-packages\PyInstaller\loader\pyimod03_importers.py", line 627, in exec_module
    exec(bytecode, module.__dict__)
  File "lib\site-packages\scipy\spatial\__init__.py", line 102, in <module>
  File "d:\skripsi\colorharmonization-master\venv\lib\site-packages\PyInstaller\loader\pyimod03_importers.py", line 627, in exec_module
    exec(bytecode, module.__dict__)
  File "lib\site-packages\scipy\spatial\_procrustes.py", line 11, in <module>
  File "d:\skripsi\colorharmonization-master\venv\lib\site-packages\PyInstaller\loader\pyimod03_importers.py", line 627, in exec_module
    exec(bytecode, module.__dict__)
  File "lib\site-packages\scipy\linalg\__init__.py", line 195, in <module>
  File "d:\skripsi\colorharmonization-master\venv\lib\site-packages\PyInstaller\loader\pyimod03_importers.py", line 627, in exec_module
    exec(bytecode, module.__dict__)
  File "lib\site-packages\scipy\linalg\misc.py", line 5, in <module>
  File "d:\skripsi\colorharmonization-master\venv\lib\site-packages\PyInstaller\loader\pyimod03_importers.py", line 627, in exec_module
    exec(bytecode, module.__dict__)
  File "lib\site-packages\scipy\linalg\blas.py", line 215, in <module>
ImportError: DLL load failed: The specified module could not be found.
[14240] Failed to execute script main
```

Answer (score 2):

With PyInstaller 3.4, it's possible that some dynamic libraries for scipy are not properly loaded because their locations have changed to a different directory, i.e. under site-packages/scipy/.libs

You need to edit **PyInstaller/hooks/hook-scipy.py** file so the libraries are search under site-packages/scipy/.libs

The fix can be found 
[here](https://github.com/pyinstaller/pyinstaller/commit/0d7ac32da25624159b805da65b91b64bf95e9a48)
and you can get the latest file from [github](https://github.com/pyinstaller/pyinstaller/blob/develop/PyInstaller/hooks/hook-scipy.py)

You may also have to edit **PyInstaller/hooks/hook-numpy.py** if your application depends on the numpy module too

Answer (score 0):

My answer on this thread might be of help to include various resources upon `fbs freeze`.

In your case you can check `lib\site-packages\scipy\linalg\blas.py", line 215` to see which `.dll` is being referenced.

[The 'google-api-python-client' distribution was not found and is required by the application with pyinstaller](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/61510900/the-google-api-python-client-distribution-was-not-found-and-is-required-by-the/61531259#61531259)